# UITableView with custom cells is empty

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a two custom cells implemented:

```
class TextFieldCell: UITableViewCell{
    var label = UILabel()
    var textField = UITextField()

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        label.text = "Name"
        textField.placeholder = "Enter Task Name Here"
        addSubview(label)
        addSubview(textField)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}

class SwitchCell : UITableViewCell {
    var label = UILabel()
    var switchControl = UISwitch()

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        label.text = "State"
        switchControl.on = true
        addSubview(label)
        addSubview(switchControl)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

In my table view class i have declared this two cells:

```
let textFieldCell = TextFieldCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: "textFieldCell")
let switchCell = SwitchCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: "switchCell")
```

and have delegate method in it:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0: return textFieldCell
        case 1: return switchCell
        default: return UITableViewCell()
        }
    }
```

But when table view loads i've see only switch control on the left of second row. I don't know why.

Comment: have you  set all datasource and delegate?

Comment: there should be more than one row in numberOfRowsInSection block and try to set label text colour black (it might be same as background colour, so use different colours).

Comment: @Madangupta yes it is (return 2 in numberOfRowsInSection) different colours dont helps.

Comment: @AndreyM. I have added the solutions. Please go through it . It will definitely solve your problem

Comment: if let  cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("switchCell") as? SwitchCell { - You should normally have something like this, in your cellForRowAtIndexPath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
private let reuseIdentifier = "switchCell"
//identifier of your cell.
```

Seems you have missed registering the cell.

```
    let tableNib = UINib(nibName:"SwitchCell", bundle:nil)
    self.tableView!.registerNib(tableNib,forCellReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier)
```

Answer (score 0):

TextFieldCell Added below Code in ViewDidLoad of TableViewCell

---

```
self.tableView.registerClass(SwitchCell, forCellReuseIdentifier: "switchCell")
self.tableView.registerClass(TextFieldCell, forCellReuseIdentifier: "textFieldCell")
```